# Shrine.rb - How to access the file path / raw file after it's been uploaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shrine

I have some other tasks that can be performed on images. Like for instance selecting multiple images, and combining them into a single image. I have that part working with RMagick and local files, and I have the upload part working with Shrine, but I need to connect the two. Once an image has been uploaded (ideally the solution should work with either local filesystem storage and S3), how can I get access to the file again, to manipulate it with ImageMagick/RMagick? I assume if I'm using S3, I'll need to DL the images from S3 to the server and store them temporarily? Is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can download any uploaded file to a temporary file using `Shrine::UploadedFile#download`:

```
tempfile = photo.image.download
# or
tempfile = photo.image[:original].download
```

This returns a `Tempfile` instance, which is a wrapper around `File`, so you can access the location on disk via `#path`:

```
system "convert #{tempfile.path} -resize 500x500 output.jpg"
```

For image processing I would recommend the [ImageProcessing](https://github.com/janko-m/image_processing) gem, which automatically generates a `Tempfile` as the result (which is closed & deleted on garbage collection if it hasn't been previously).

Comment: Thanks, @janko-m! This is what I was looking for.